# Kubernetes pods restarting on Azure

Tags: azure, kubernetes

When utilising Azure Container Service (Kubernetes provider) I am seeing a number of my pods randomly restart at exactly the same time?

Randomly, it seems to affect all pods apart from a daemonset pod I have and the kube proxy. All other pods restart including the kube-system pods such as DNS, Heapster and dashboard.

Can anyone point me in the right direction for understanding why the pods are restarting? Nothing seems to jump out on the syslog file and I couldn't find the kubelet log on Azure?

Comment: We need more information here, logfiles or pod output or events, anything really to help narrow it down.

Comment: Sure thing lack of knowledge on my part at the time on how to get this information. If I experience it again I'll post a new questions many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to troubleshoot please run the following command: `kubectl get events`, then post the results here.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the command - lack of experience on my part on which commands to run to try and diagnose. If it happens again I'll try the 'get events' action and post an updated question - will accept this answer for guidance thank you